# C# Parser generator that runs as a source generator

Tags: c#, parsing, parser-generator, sourcegenerators

There are many parser generators for C#, but all that I've found laud the fact that there is no build step. As someone building a redistributable, trimmable, AOT optimized library, that is a *downside*.

I would love a source generator that takes my grammar and generates code, automatically, adding no dependencies. Does this exist?

Comment: Making your own custom code generator is really easy since .net 7 It's just a class implementing `ISourceGenerator` and a method that will go through your source code and allow you to create new files using `context.AddSource` method.